# Can't reach Cuda's some dll while running keras with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

**Problem**
I'm trying to run Keras on my GPU. I have an ASUS FX550V 6GB with a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 950M 2Go. I installed CUDA 8 and cudnn 6 but when i run my model i 
got these 
[image]

I already set my variable environment so python knows where are the tools to run on GPU.

Do you know how to solve the problem ?

I looked for answers on google and it says that i didn't installed CUDA or I didn't set my environment variable so that i did it.

Comment: pleas post any outputs as text, and not as screen shots.
also, describe what have you done so far

Comment: I already explain what i did in my post

Comment: I mean what you did to solve the problem. For example, what does googling the error message return?

Comment: Is it Cuda 8.0 and CuDNN 6.1?

Comment: @DanielMöller yes

Comment: Did you configure all environment vars for CuDNN? (It must be 6.1, though, different versions may not work) -- Cuda and CuDNN are two different things, and both must have its environment vars: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007279/tensorflow-on-windows-couldnt-open-cuda-library-cudnn64-5-dll

Comment: @DanielMöller i pasted the cudnn dll into cuda folder, respecting the folder's name.

Comment: There is probably a dir named like something 64. You should follow exactly the instructions in the CuDNN site. https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

Comment: @DanielMöller I tried to do all the steps exactly how it's explained, but can't find the problem